# pattern for accepting number range?

Tags: regex, html

What pattern should i use to accept number range such as 100 - 200?

```
<input type="text" pattern="" name="numRange">
```

Also if it is possible to make sure the min is lower than max. i.e 100 - 200 here 100 should be lower than 200. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "if it is possible to make sure the min is lower than max"?

Comment: the first part before - is small than the part after -.

Comment: You probably want to work with type `number`: `<input type="number" step="1" min="100" max="200">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) in the comments you could validate a number range like so:

```html
<form action="somefile.php">
  <input type="number" step="1" min="100" max="200" id="numRange">
</form>
```

Regex Method (less recommended):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('numRange');

input.oninvalid = function(event) {
  event.target.setCustomValidity('number range should be betweeb 100-200')
}
```

```html
<form action="somefile.php">
  <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="100-200" pattern="^(1\d\d|200)$" id="numRange">
</form>
```

The main difference between the two methods is the first uses `type="number"`, and the second relies regex, `javascript` and uses `type="text"`).

Comment: That's right. You could also shorten the regex to `(1\d\d|200)`. Ends anchors are applied by default: `pattern="(1\d\d|200)"`.